# Acumatica add new screen

Tags: customization, acumatica

Can we add a completely new screen to Acumatica rather than customizing existing screen?

This is not discussed in T100 Guide so was curious to know.

Comment: yes. it might be in T300 if not maybe T200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Brendan said, it will be in a different guide, but the steps are as follows when you use visual studio primarily.

- Create a new Graph Define a Primary View for the graph and related
  views
- Build the project
- Create a page to the correct sub folder under the pages with the
  right acumatica template eg: FormDetail or FormTab
- set up the primary view for data source and generate controls
- Add sitemap in acumatica to show your new page

Answer (score 1):

But this is not a good way to creating a screen. You can also create it from Customization of your project (System - Customization - Customization Project).
Select Screens Tab, select add screen, New screen, will be provided a Window with initial properties for creating a screen. There you will see what need to do (new PXGraph name, a site map for that screen, name of the screen, and number eg: SO301010, but you need to set number that not busy.)

Comment: All good ways to create a screen. I would agree that newer version of Acumatica do a great job automating some of the pluming right in a site/instance. I do find it easier to use a site to create the objects which i then transfer into visual studio.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it briefly

Comment: Mostly a matter of preference, both ways will work, you can mix and match too.

Comment: I am not able to edit the DAC for new fields on the custom screen it gives an error saying " Could not load type 'NewScreen.POedit+InventoryItem' "